# Infinite redirect loop?

Tags: 301-redirect

I want dev.test.com, to go to a specific directory, `/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot`. Here's my apache2 conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.test.com
        Redirect permanent / /var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

I keep getting successive `301 Moved permanently` responses (until the server stops sending them, or is it the browser stops requesting them?)

```
GET dev.test.com: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
GET webroot: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
GET webroot: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
[...] 21 requests later (seriously):
GET webroot: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webrootvar/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/
```

I found these responses via firebug. Anyone know what the problem could be? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Redirect, isn't what you need a DocumentRoot?

What you're doing here is sending a redirect back to the client.  Therefore, what's happening is that Apache's prepending the name of the current VHost onto the redirect target string, and sending:

```
Location: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
```

Of course, when that hits, it finds the dev.test.com VHost, and lo and behold! there's a Redirect in there that applies to this request.  So it happily sends you to http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/(yourrequeststring), which works out to:

```
Location: http://dev.test.com/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot/var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
```

Make sense now?  At any rate, what you need is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot
    <Directory /var/www/cakephp/dev/webroot>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from none
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The  section is optional; add it only if you get 403's when you try to use the site with the new DocumentRoot directive in place.